# Decrypt AES encrypted data in swift encrypted by CryptoJS

Tags: swift

```
func decrypt() -> String {
        var result = ""
        do {
            let aes = try AES(key: Constant.AES.key.bytes, blockMode: .CBC(iv: Constant.AES.key.bytes))
            let temp = try aes.decrypt(self.bytes)
            result = String(bytes: temp, encoding: .utf8)!
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        return result
    }
```

Not able to decrypt used many lib like cryptoswift and cyrptoJS swift

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 500 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.

Comment: The catch is to determine what the parameters and encodings are used for CryptoJS. Spend sone time with the CryptoJS encryption docs. Provide a [mcve] incloudig test data, results, etv..

Comment: @zaph you should update your values, keep copy&paste the same answer. It's more like 8 times slower, not 1000 ;-)

Comment: @Marcin Publish some benchmarks, the last time I benchmarked it was 500 to 1000 times slower but you are right I have not benchmarked recently, that is your job.. Also, there is no reason to use one-off AES implementations when there FIPS certified versions provided by Apple that are faster. Further what proofs are there that no timing flaws exist in the implementation that might make it vulnerable to timing and/or power attacks and thus insecure. There needs to be a disclaimer not to use the code when a high level of security is required.

Comment: @Marcin I am **not** accusing you but it is known that government agencies seed venerable crypto implementations so non-FIPS certified non substantially vetted implementations are to be avoided in instances when a high level of security is required.

Comment: @zaph you should know by now that I'm not a USA citizen and *that* agencies have no power over me nor the project. In contrary to the USA based companies ;)))) I'm not accusing, just saying.

Comment: The point of FIPS 140-2 certification is code is validation, review/testing by an independent organization that meets U.S. government standards. The Cryptographic Module Validation Program (CMVP), headed by NIST, provides module and algorithm testing requirements for FIPS 140-2.  It is the independent validation by an accepted 3rd party organization that is the important part.